# How to use gcc to generate all possible binary files from object files

Tags: linux, gcc

Does anyone know how to use gcc  to generate all possible binary files from object files ? I know you can use : "gcc -MM" to generate all the .o files for some given source files.

But how would you use gcc  to generate all possible binary files from object files
in a project ?

Example: I use "gcc -MM" to generate: a.o, b.o, c.o, d.o
If one were trying to generate a list of binaries files built from each of the .o files like this:

```
a: b.o c.o d.o
b: a.o c.o d.o
c: a.o b.o d.o
d: a.o b.o b.o
```

I can do this with a Perl script, but I was just curious if there was some way to do it with gcc

Thanks

Comment: I cannot see how to map "generate all the .o files" to what `gcc -MM` actually does. Do you mean that you want to generate files or *a list of filenames?* And when you say "all possible binary files", do you mean only executables? Or libraries too, or what? (An example would be very helpful.)

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague, I updated it with an example. I am a relative newbie with gcc so I worded the question poorly

Comment: Your example is very unclear, but I'll attempt an answer.

Comment: My goal was to find the smallest amount of code to auto declare executables while listing all the .o files in a makefile (in case anyone else was wondering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer, *"no, but..."***

`gcc -MM` can give you `foo.o: bar.h` because `foo.cc` contains the directive:

```
#include "bar.h"
```

That's easy. But `foo.cc` can also contain the declaration:

```
int bar_f1(int);
```

How can gcc know which object file contains the binary code for this function? Or if there are *two* object files containing functions with this signature, which it should use? It can't.

...Unless...

**Long answer, *"yes, if..."***

If you refrain from giving source files forward declarations of things in other source files, and also refrain from giving a header file declarations of anything not contained in *the corresponding source file*, and also give the source file containing `int main(...)` a fixed name like, say, `main.cc`, then you can take the output of `gcc -MM`:

```
bar.o: bar.h baz.h
foo.o: bar.h
main.o: foo.h zot.h
pan.o: pan.h
zot.o: zot.h
```

and transform it without too much trouble (using e.g Perl or sed) into:

```
main: bar.o foo.o zot.o
```

In theory you could get by without these restrictions(*) by scanning the object files and constructing the dependency tree; this might be equivalent to scanning for the presence of `int main(...)`, segregating those files and linking each of them against all the others, or just listing them, if all you want is a list of possible executables without dependencies **(I'm still not sure exactly what you want)**. These things still require some scripting on your part, I know of no way to do them with gcc alone.

(*)You must still refrain from having two definitions of the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know one could list all the  .o files when declaring an executable. That makes it alot easier. I know which files have a main() function. My goal was to get the smallest amount of code to auto declare executables while listing all the .o files

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp: 1) Why should I? 2) You haven't upvoted my answer, although you acknowledge that it was useful. 3) I didn't downvote.

Comment: 1) I think this question may be helpful to others in the future 2) Thank you !